# Disable certain suggestions in PhpStorm search

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I’m not sure what are these called:

[image]

I mean the *Show code with my wire stats*, *Show Memory indicator*, etc..

Basically, I’m mostly interested so this autocomplete menu would only show files, or at the very least would prioritise files. How can this be achieved?

I’m in version 2022.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That popup is called **Search Everywhere** and you are on an "All" tab that includes combined results from Classes, Files, Symbols, Actions etc.

Either manually switch to the desired tab (using a mouse or by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> needed number of times) or invoke this popup for the desired search from the start. For that just use the shortcut for `Navigate | File...` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> here on Windows keymap).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html

[image]

[image]

---

> Found the solution.
>
> These things are called `Actions`, and the can be disabled in menu that appears after clicking the small funnel icon in the top right:
>
> I tested, these changes seem to 'survive' a restart.

Yes, at the moment it is remembered only during the session.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229285 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified about any progress.

*(P.S. The same happens with Find in Files popup ([IDEA-143972](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143972)) and a few others similar popups as well)*